# Orange seedling leaf browning, curling, slowed growth? Please help!

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, leaves

I am a 1st time citrus planter. I planted an orange seedling in some potting mix after it germinated. Within the 1st few wks there was pretty impressive growth of leaves and height. it is now about 9wks old and i realized the growth has been stunted--haven't seen significant new leaves and the current ones has issues.

Main concern is the bottom leaf tip is browning for the past few days and I'm not sure what it is and if salvageable? I'm not sure if it's a cotyledon that's supposed to fall off but seems like it's a true leaf....

Other concern is the leaf on top is droopy and not as green as the others.

My watering regimen had been pretty consistent for the 1st 5-6 wks of growth..I would water it with tap water every few days when the top of soil looks dried. At about week 4 or 5 after 2sets of leaves had sprouted I did put some indoor plant fertilizer spritz in the soil.

I live in southern california..this tree is kept on a south facing windowsill.  Over the past few wks, we have started to keep our orchids by the same windowsill and it is next to my tree...I'm hoping it is not a fungus or pest from the orchid that is attacking my tree (I dont see any issues with my orchid leaves though)

What can I do to save my tree??? I'm tempted to cut off the unhealthy part of the bottom leaf if it's a true leaf and not cotyledon[image][image][image]

Comment: Water less (citrus is a plant of dry places), and give it also real sun. (so open windows or put them outside on sunny days): windows block sun.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you think I should replant it to dryer potting mix if it's too watered? If its root rot I dont want it to rot more while waiting for the soil to dry

Comment: I do not think you should repot (I think it is more physiological repose of the plant). But wait some more time for real answers: if I remember correctly we have a citrus expert.

Comment: Wait, do not put this outside in the sun without acclimatizing.  If you have a covered porch, that would be fine.  No direct sun unless 2 to 3 weeks of acclimatization. 'Sunburn' of a plant with thin epidermis will kill that plant.  This little guy is in TOO large of a pot.  Do not water the entire soil in this pot...just enough to dampen the roots. The roots of this tiny plant.  You have definitely got too much water going on here as well as too big of a pot of chunky potting mix?  What is a fertilizer spritz?

Answer (score 1):

> "Water less (citrus is a plant of dry places), and give it also real sun. (so open windows or put them outside on sunny days): windows block sun."
>
> "I do not think you should repot (I think it is more physiological repose of the plant)."
> ~Giacomo Catenazzi

---

> "Wait, do not put this outside in the sun without acclimatizing. If you have a covered porch, that would be fine. No direct sun unless 2 to 3 weeks of acclimatization. 'Sunburn' of a plant with thin epidermis will kill that plant. This little guy is in TOO large of a pot. Do not water the entire soil in this pot...just enough to dampen the roots. The roots of this tiny plant. You have definitely got too much water going on here as well as too big of a pot of chunky potting mix."
> ~stormy

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a very late response, as I have only just discovered this site, but maybe this will be of interest to other readers.
While at the mention of 'salt' many people will say this guy is crazy, but plant nutrition has fascinated me for years - and in particular - the provision of vital trace elements by way of 'companion planting'. 
A friend often phones me up for suggestions as to what is going wrong with his fruit farm. Some time ago, the problem was much the same as your's, but for mulberries.
Himalayan salt evidently contains 84 trace elements, and I suggested he give the one of the trees a 'foliar feed' with a solution. 
Just a few days later he phoned up and said: "I have heard of miracles before, but I have never witnessed one till now! I will be spraying all my trees with the Himalayan salt, I have never seen any plant respond so favourable or so quickly to any treatment." I love helping people.